# Replacing sub string containing special characters in a string with another character

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, replace

I have a string like

```
ilp-bm-qa-reports-crud-test-${__P(DOMAIN,staging1)}.csv
```

I want to replace `${__P(DOMAIN,staging1)}`  so that the output is

```
ilp-bm-qa-reports-crud-test-dev.csv
```

How to do that?

Also I want to store output in variable to that it can be used on next step

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ s='ilp-bm-qa-reports-crud-test-${__P(DOMAIN,staging1)}.csv'
$ echo "${s/\${__P(DOMAIN,staging1)\}/dev}"
ilp-bm-qa-reports-crud-test-dev.csv
```

To save in variable

```
$ newvar="${s/\${__P(DOMAIN,staging1)\}/dev}"
$ echo "$newvar"
ilp-bm-qa-reports-crud-test-dev.csv
```

Comment: thanks, you really saved my day. I was missing escape characters while replacing.